# google map v3 dragging marker issue

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google map api V3, and in my application i m making gradable marker. Every thing is working fine except the marker icon while dragging.

What happens in Google Map V2 was it changes marker icon automatically when it was being dragged but in Google Map V3 when dragging the marker its icon doesn't change like it used to change in V2.

Comment: That's correct, V2 and V3 are different. :-)
The V2 marker animation is considered superfluous in V3, which aims to be as lightweight as possible for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks, can you please post this comment as answer so that i can mark it as answer. It will help others too.

Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: in V3 they removed it, since they considered the animation to be of little use in mobile devices. They are trying to aim this V3 release to be as lightweight as possible.